# Ionic cordova build android cannot find module rxjs/Observable

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to create android app using this guide -
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/getting-started/

When I enter `ionic serve` or `ionic cordova build android` , I get the error

```
Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plu gin-cordova). 
Error : Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
```

I have tried

```
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
> 
> npm cache clean 
> 
> npm install -g @angular/cli
```

but still same error. Then I tried `npm install rxjs -g` , still same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you really intend to install rxjs globally? Does your package.json have a rxjs in the dependencies? if not you probably wanted to do npm install rxjs --save as the final step.. And if it was there an npm init would probably have sufficed, before doing ionic serve

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it's there in the dependencies, but I'm not sure why it's just not detected.

Comment: You should be making sure it's installed at the project level and be seeing it in the node_modules folder... so it'll be something like node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts that's present.

Comment: hmm ya, it's not in my node_modules folder. Is there anyway I can download rxjs folder and manually copy and paste it in ? I couldn't seem to be able to find it online. Thanks again

Comment: I would have thought the npm init would have done that... if it's in package.json. if all else fails try npm install rxjs@<version in package.json> as a brute force approach.

Comment: BTW: Sometimes there may be a file called package-lock.json file present too. - rename it or delete it. But that sometimes may prevent you from doing stuff too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to install it. Anyway I can mark your answer as correct? Since you commented under my question, I can't mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Well just upvote the comment that solved it for you.